# Hi, when I am running the below code, I am getting length as 1. Shouldn't the length be zero since we did not pass anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
class a {
    constructor(size) {
         this.data = new Array(size);
    }
}

var b = new a();
console.log(b.data.length);
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I just cant seem to figure out why the length is 1 I thought it would be 0. I recently started learning programming.

Comment: "_since we did not pass anything_" You _are_ passing something to the Array constructor. You are passing `size`(regardless of what value `size` has). See the [documentation of the Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#Parameters) about how the parameters work.

Answer (score 2):

size is the `undefined`, and `new Array(size)` will return the array that has the one element which value is undefined - `[ undefined ]`.

[Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) has 2 cases. If you pass the number as a parameter, it will create an array with its length property set to that number. If not, array will be initialized with the given elements.

```js
class a {

  constructor(size) {
    this.data = new Array(size);
    console.log(this.data)
  }
}

var b = new a();
console.log(b.data.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of size if undefined. Insted of taking it as the size of the array. its taking it as the first element of the array. So this.data is actually an array will one element of value undefined.